# only working days on case in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've executed the following case in a query:

```
 WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
```

But I want to add `+2` working days. How can I achieve that?

Example:
Lets say that we have an ID with *insertion date* NULL and priority 1 minor and creation date on Friday 15/01/2016.
The output should be:

```
115   prio1   minor  acknowledge_date 19/01/2016
```

Comment: Give an example of your required output and your table layout.

Comment: What do you mean +2? to add 2 days in value to a date?

Comment: Also, please include your DBMS.  Date functions vary widely across the various RDBMSs.

Comment: date function is to_date('11/01/2016','dd/mm/rrrr')

Comment: exapmle lets say that we have an id with insertion date null and priority 1 minor and creation date on Friday 15/01/2016 the result must me

115 prio1 minor acknowledge_date 19/012016

Comment: You literally want your string to return "115 prio1 minor acknowledge_date 19/012016"?  Just clarifying...  is this Oracle?

Comment: Yes its oracle im sorry im completely noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a total shot in the dark, but you mentioned you wanted to add two work days, and the example you gave (January 16 + 2 work days = January 19) tells me you mean you want to skip weekends.  If this is the case, I think something like this might work:

```
select
  case
    when phases is null and
      insertiondate is null and
      priority = 1 and
      complexity = 'minor' then
        case to_char(creationdate, 'D')
          when '5' then to_char(creationdate + 4, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
          when '6' then to_char(creationdate + 4, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
          when '7' then to_char(creationdate + 3, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
          else to_char(creationdate + 2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        end
  end
from test
```

In essence, I'm doing a poor man's, brute-force business day calculation of "2 work days" by saying on Thursday and Friday, 2 business days = 4 calendar days, on Saturday, 2 business days = 3 calendar days, and all other days 2 days = 2 days.

It wouldn't shock me if this misses the mark, but maybe it's a starting point for clarification.

For the following create days, it returns the following results:

```
Creation date           Result
1/15/2016 9:28:31 AM    19/01/2016
1/16/2016 9:41:49 AM    19/01/2016
1/17/2016 9:41:51 AM    19/01/2016
1/18/2016 9:41:52 AM    20/01/2016
1/19/2016 9:41:54 AM    21/01/2016
1/21/2016 9:42:00 AM    25/01/2016
```

Comment: Thnx alot for your input this is exactly that im looking for!